# Не сходится задача с ответом

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Решаю задачу, не сходится с ответом и не понимаю в чем проблема. Можете объяснить подробнее, где я ошибся. Мой ответ: -6, правильный ответ: 9.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRv8t.jpg

```
var
  a: array[1..1000] of Integer;
  n, i, j, x: Integer;
begin
  x := -10000;

  readln(n);

  for i := 1 to n do
    Readln(a[i]);

  for i := 1 to n - 5 do
    for j := i + 5 to n do
      if ((a[i] - a[j]) mod 3 = 0) and ((a[i] - a[j]) > x ) then
        x := (a[i] - a[j]);

  if x <> - 10000 then
    Writeln(x)
  else
    Writeln('NO');

  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Приведите код в самом вопросе, а не по ссылке.

Comment: Согласен, приведите код пожалуйста. И мне непонятно почему i до N - 5 а j от i + 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Главная ошибка это, то что в задаче под разностью понимается абсолютное значение, в отличии от того, что представлено в решении. Т.е. всего лишь требуется заменить на

```
abs(a[i] - a[j])
```

В этом случае разность не может быть отрицательна, поэтому начальное значение нужно брать ноль.